# Is there ever a reason for "? 1 : 0" in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, conditional-operator

*Computer Organization and Design* (5th edition) by Hennessy and Patterson includes this Verilog code in Figure B.5.15 (p. B-37):

```
ALUOut <= A < B ? 1:0;
```

Is there any reason not to write this simpler statement instead:

```
ALUOut <= A < B;
```

In general, is there ever a reason to write "? 1 : 0" in Verilog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only people that can answer why they chose one way or the other are the authors. Many of the same people prefer to write `if (expr != 0)` instead `if (expr)`. Maybe they come from VHDL and want to be more explicit.

The only reason I can think of why writing `expression ? 1: 0` might be needed is when the expression evaluates to 'z and you want to convert it to 'x.